# Sed replacement not working inside Bash Script Loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, csv, sed

I am unable to replace string in my txt file using the sed command inside a loop. The description of my problem and the code I had used are as follow:

I have two tables as follow.

Table **adminuser.txt**

```
48 yimenju
50 dolwdow
```

Table **result.txt**

```
yimenju 1
yimenju 2
dolwdow 3
```

I want to replace the user_name in result.txt with the corresponding user_id from adminuser.txt. The linux bash script I had used are as follow:

```
filename="temp.txt"
input="adminuser.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line > $filename
    user_id="$(cut -d ' ' -f 1 $filename)"
    user_name="$(cut -d ' ' -f 2 $filename)"
    sed -i "s/$user_name/$user_id/g" result.txt
done < "$input"
```

My desired output is as follow:
Table **result.txt**

```
48 1
48 2
50 3
```

Comment: What role does `temp.txt` play in your logic if all you really need is the other two?

Comment: Update your question and put the desired result, output...

Comment: I am using `temp.txt` to dump one line at a time instead of reading from `adminuser.txt` which has multiple lines. Since, as far as I know `cut` operates on a file, which is why I needed `temp.txt` to read one line at a time.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [Help] See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1}NR!=FNR{$1=a[$1];print}' adminuser.txt result.txt > result.txt.tmp && mv result.txt.tmp result.txt
```

Demonstrable success:

```
$ cat adminuser.txt 
48  yimenju
50  dolwdow
$ cat result.txt 
yimenju 1
yimenju 2
dolwdow 3
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1}NR!=FNR{$1=a[$1];print}' adminuser.txt result.txt > result.txt.tmp && mv result.txt.tmp result.txt 
$ cat result.txt 
48 1
48 2
50 3
$
```

Comment: The first column gets removed (instead of replaced) with this cmd in the `result.txt` file.

Comment: Not on my system with the files you provided ... it does exactly what you asked (or what I think you asked for). I'll edit my answer w/ the given inputs and the final result @jalaluddin

Comment: @jalaluddin may be your input has dos-style line endings? What's the output of `file adminuser.txt result.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to embed an external tool/utility like `sed`, `cut` inside the `bash` shell loop, something like:

---

```
filename="temp.txt"
input="adminuser.txt"

while read -ru9 admin_id admin_user; do
  while read -r result_user result_id; do
    [[ "$admin_user" = "$result_user" ]] && {
      printf '%s %s\n' "$admin_id" "$result_id"
    }
  done < result.txt
done 9< "$input" > "$filename" && mv "$filename" result.txt
```

---

- The above solution would be *very very* slow when it comes to a large/data input. so the `awk` solution would be a correct approach.